# Folder hierarchy for files shared with user in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I have a site in which there is a document library. When user 'A' creates a folder 'Test'in the document library, a SharePoint Designer Workflow runs which removes the permission of other users and only 'user A' has full access to it. Now when user 'A' uploads a document in the folder 'Test' and share it with user 'B'. User 'B' get an email link for document which is Ok. When user 'B' directly access the site, he is not able to see 'test' folder. I want to make it accessible so he can navigate to the file but wont be able to see other documents that are not shared with him. Is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like that would be difficult to manage.  It's normal that User B is unable to see the 'test' folder, since the user does not have permission to see it.  Instead of completely removing User B's permissions to a folder created by User A, perhaps you could give User B read permissions instead of read/write permissions?  This would solve the issue for you (unless of course, User B is not allowed to even see documents unless User A specifically shares them).

Comment: User B is not allowed to even view the documents in test folder unless user A explicitly shares with him. Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: I agree with what Mr Doe wrote in his answer, I'm also not keen on lots of folders.  You need to give some thought to the structure of your documents, whatever form you end up using.  I would also say it is better to use separate Document Libraries to manage this.  Security / Permissions would become too difficult and obscure to manage otherwise.  [This blog](https://sharepointmaven.com/folder-vs-library-sharepoint/) has lots of useful info, check out posts on Document Management, Security and Information Management.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is because you have removed all permissions from the folder, but what you really need to do is differentiate between view permissions and edit permissions.

Essentially User B would require View Permissions for the 'Test' folder but not for all the other files in said folder.

This is why folders are generally not considered best practice in SharePoint Production environments. I would recommend instead that users create an entirely new library rather than a new folder.

Comment: If there are 1000 employees, there would be 1000 libraries in the Site Content. Wouldn't that be a bad practice. Please suggest.

Comment: On that scale perhaps folders are a better option, but managing it will be difficult depending on your requirements. Essentially if you require that other users can 'see' the folders but not the files inside unless they have been shared with them, your workflow would have to allow view permissions but remove view permissions for every file inside the folder.

Personally I wouldn't have an issue with 1000 Libraries but I would have to look up whether there are limitations on the SharePOint side and if it is accepted practice.